# CSS / HTML bugged menu

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my menu, I'm just a beginner and I'm learning.

The problem is: My menu goes in three lines. (I need only one, straight line.) I tried `display:inline` but it doesn't work.

MY CSS like this:

```
 body {
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    background-image: url("img/bgr.png");
}

.header {
    text-align:center;
    margin:0px auto;
}

#header {
    height:300px;
    width:960px;
    background-image:url("img/top.png")
}
#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#menu li a  {
    color:#fff; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    display:block; 
    background:url(img/manu.png); 
    padding:0 10px 0 10px;  
    height:54px; 
    width: 150px;

    line-height:54px;
}

#menu li a:hover {
    color:#fff; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    background:url(img/manu1.png);  
    height:54px; 
    width:150px;
    line-height:54px;
}
```

And my HTML like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Pagrindinis Puslapis</title>
</head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<body>
<div class="header" id="header">
    <tekstas><br><br><br><br><br><br>http://www.profilio.com</tekstas>
    </div>
<div class="header" id='menu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Pagrindinis</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Kontaktai</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Paslaugos</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>


    
</body>
</html>
```

Have no idea what's wrong....

Adding some extra text

Comment: Please try to describe your problem more clearly in your question itself. What exactly is bugged? What should it do and what does it do instead?

Comment: EDIT:
The problem is: Menu goes in three lines( I need only one), and the imagebackground is spammed... I only need him to appear when I enter a new menu item <li></li>

Comment: As a small sidenote: Don't use `<br><br><br><br><br><br>` to add space. Use `margin` or `padding` instead. It's much cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The links are set to `display:block` and so they wrap. They do not line up by default.

If you set the `li` to `display:inline-block` they will only be as wide as they need to be which is dtermined by the size of the links.

```css
.header {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  background: green;
}
#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#menu li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  background: blue;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  height: 54px;
  line-height: 54px;
  width:150px;
}
#menu li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: red;
  height: 54px;
  line-height: 54px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header" id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Pagrindinis</span></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Kontaktai</span></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>Paslaugos</span></a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: I changed my question a bit, I realised, that I missed width in menu li a style

Comment: http://s4.postimg.org/fswu35vwt/ketvirtas.png this is what I get after your Edit. And another problem appeared: space between header and menu

Comment: @Tomas Can you try to reproduce your issue in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with minimal amount of code? (don't just copy&paste the entire site code in it) It will be much easier to debug your issue with the code instead of just screenshots.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cvk5a3nn/

well the code is small enough , don't know what to delete. Maybe there is a problem it other things.

Comment: @Tomas [Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/cvk5a3nn/1/). You had the `display: inline-block;` on the `#menu li a` element instead of the `#menu li` element.

Comment: oh damn. that did work. thank you very much. One more questoin: how do I align menu content to left, I mean my menu is now in the center , how to start from left of the header.

I entered:         `margin-left:-550px;
    margin-top:-0.5px;` on the #menu ul, but maybe there is a other way?

Comment: @Tomas That's because you have `text-align:center;` on the `.header`. It will center anything in it, including the `li` blocks. If you only want the text inside the blocks to be centered, put `text-align:center;` on the `li` element instead.